# wxTimer not calling callback after binding with Bind()

Tags: c++, callback, wxwidgets

I'd like to use wxTimer in my application, but I don't want to use the preprocessor macros to bind the events. Instead I want to use `Bind()` during the CTOR call to bind the events to my ui elements.
After binding my timer, it doesn't start or it doesn't call the event handler. According to [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwij4df7jLjuAhX1wQIHHbdZChIQFjAAegQICBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fforums.wxwidgets.org%2Fviewtopic.php%3Ft%3D41836&usg=AOvVaw0YfhLmgG75m7_SJGm5mwLF) it ought to work like I want to. I also do not want to use `Connect()`. Binding a button in the same way works just fine. Here is a minimal example:

minimum example:

```cpp
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <iostream>

class MainFrame : public wxFrame
{
private:
    const int DELTA_TIME = 100; // time between timer events (in ms)
private:
    wxTimer* timer = nullptr;
    void OnTimer(wxTimerEvent& evt);
    void OnButtonClick(wxCommandEvent& evt);
public:
    MainFrame();
    virtual ~MainFrame();
};

void MainFrame::OnTimer(wxTimerEvent& evt)
{
    std::cout << "Timer Event!" << std::endl; // never happens
}

void MainFrame::OnButtonClick(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
    std::cout << "Button Event!" << std::endl; // works just fine
}

MainFrame::MainFrame()
    : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "Test", wxPoint(0, 0), wxSize(600, 400))
{
    timer = new wxTimer(this, wxID_ANY);
    timer->Bind(
        wxEVT_TIMER,                    // evt type
        &MainFrame::OnTimer,            // callback
        this,                           // parent
        timer->GetId()                  // id
    );
    timer->Start(DELTA_TIME, wxTIMER_CONTINUOUS);

    wxButton* testBtn = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, "Test", wxPoint(20, 20));
    testBtn->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MainFrame::OnButtonClick, this);
}

MainFrame::~MainFrame()
{
    if (timer->IsRunning())
    {
        timer->Stop();
    }
}

// application class
class Main : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(Main)

bool Main::OnInit()
{
    MainFrame* mainFrame = new MainFrame();
    SetTopWindow(mainFrame);
    mainFrame->Show();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change

```
timer->Bind(...
```

to just

```
Bind(...
```

The line `timer = new wxTimer(this, wxID_ANY);` sets the main frame to be the owner of the timer, so that is the item notified when the timer is fired. However the line `timer->Bind(...` sets up the timer to process the timer events.  But the events aren't sent to the timer, they're sent to the main frame. So it is necessary to set the main frame to be the event handler, which is what the change given above does.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does that mean that I should change button->Bind to Bind(), too?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I will do so from now on. I'm fairly new to wx. does that also mean that if you don't supply an ID in the bind() call you will bind all timer events to that callback? and can you bind multiple callbacks to some event? in which order are they fired if so?

Comment: Sorry I confused myself and my first comment was so wrong I had to delete it. But the line `testBtn->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON` is fine. Buttons and other controls dont have anything analogous to an owner like a timer does. Events are thrown to them directly. So the line `testBtn->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON,...` sets the method `OnButtonClick` from the class `MainFrame` of the object pointed to by `this` to handle the events of type wxEVT_BUTTON for this particular button.  Since those events are thrown to the button when it is chicked, they will be handled by that method.

Comment: However (and this is the part where I confused myself in the now deleted comment), wxCommandEvents are special in that they [filter up](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html#overview_events_propagation) so that if you want, you can have the main frame handle the event if you want. You could for example handle the event like this `Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON,&MainFrame::OnButtonClick,this, testBtn->GetId(),testBtn->GetId());`  In this case this means that the main frame should handle events of type wxEVT_BUTTON where the event has the id of  testBtn by calling the OnButtonClick method.

Comment: The reason that works is because wxWidgets will first throw the event to testBtn and see that it has no handler for it. Then since wxEVT_BUTTON is a type of wxCommandEvent and wxCommandEvents filter up, wxWidgets will pass the event to the button's parent (ie the main frame) to try to handle it. If you use the long Bind command given above, the main frame will use the OnButtonClick method to handle it.

Comment: To answer the question about using ids with Bind, in the first version (`testBtn->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON,...`) we don't need an id because the button should only be receiving events of type wxEVT_BUTTON in response to its own clicks. So it is reasonable for it to handle all such events with one method. However when using the main frame to handle wxEVT_BUTTON events, if we don't supply ids (ie we just used `Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON,&MainFrame::OnButtonClick,this);`), it would use that method to handle all button click events.

Comment: In short, when binding directly to the button you don't need an id because it should only be receiving events from itself. However if binding to the main frame to handle button events, there could be many buttons in the frame, and using the ids specifies which button clicks should be handled with the given method.

Comment: Getting back to the timer events and ids, you are correct. If you just used the line `timer->Bind(wxEVT_TIMER,&MainFrame::OnTimer,this);` that would set the method to handle all timer events that the frame receives. If there will only be 1 timer event, this is fine. If you have multiple timers, you could still use a single event handler. But in the handler method, you would need to have a bunch of lines like `if ( evt.GetTimer().GetId() == timer->GetId() ){...}` to separate out which code you want to run in response to each timer.

Comment: I've spilled a lot of digital ink here, but I hope this clarifies things.  Sorry again about my first wrong comment.